# urllib2.urlopen returning an object with no info() or geturl() methods

Tags: python, http, urllib2, httpresponse

I am running Python 2.7.1 and am trying to use the urllib2 module to access some webpages. Per the Python documentation, `urllib2.urlopen()`:

> This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods,
>   `geturl()` and `info()`

However, it indicates there are no such methods when I try to access `info()` in the last print statement in the code. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'info'
```

I don't understand this. I can't find anything on Google and the documentation clearly says that these methods exist with the object returned. Interestingly enough, as indicated through the error and by testing for the methods, it IS returning an `HTTPresponse` object with those respective methods. What am I missing?

My code is as follows:

```
import urllib2 
import httplib, socket 
import cookielib
import ntlm 
from ntlm import ntlm 

url = URLOFSOMESORT
user = USERNAMEHERE
password = PASSWORD 
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
data = ""
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm() 
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password) 

cookie_jar = cookielib.CookieJar() 
cookie_handler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)
redirect = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()
auth_basic = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman) 
auth_digest = urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(passman) 
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman) 

opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_handler, auth_NTLM, auth_basic, auth_digest, redirect)
urllib2.install_opener(opener) 
request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request) 
#cookie_jar.extract_cookies(response, request)

print response.info()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the fact that you have `install_opener` receive an `HTTPNtlmAuthHandler`. When that class handles the request, it returns an `HTTPResponse` instead of the standard 'file like object'.

To see the source, go [here](http://python-ntlm.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python26/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py).

Comment: Hrmmmm....just looked. Thanks. Grrr, this stinks. Trying to extract the cookies on the response